# Hibernate Insert table id as foreign key in another table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 tables PERSON and CARD

I want my table CARD to have PERSON_ID as FK how am I suppose to do it in hibernate entity class.

[image]

Is there a way to do it through Java Classes and annotation ?

**MY PERSON ENTITY CLASS**

```
package com.managementsystem.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name="PERSON")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String card_no;
    private String rank;
    private String dte;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCard_no() {
        return card_no;
    }
    public void setCard_no(String card_no) {
        this.card_no = card_no;
    }
    public String getRank() {
        return rank;
    }
    public void setRank(String rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }
    public String getDte() {
        return dte;
    }
    public void setDte(String dte) {
        this.dte = dte;
    }

}
```

**MY CARD ENTITY CLASS**

```
package com.managementsystem.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity(name="CARD")
public class Card {

    @Id
    private int id;

    //What to do here, how to link this to person id.
    private int person_id;
    private int serial_no;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getPerson_id() {
        return person_id;
    }
    public void setPerson_id(int person_id) {
        this.person_id = person_id;
    }
    public int getSerial_no() {
        return serial_no;
    }
    public void setSerial_no(int serial_no) {
        this.serial_no = serial_no;
    }


}
```

What to do in card class so that I can enter person_id in card table which is required.

Comment: REASON OF DOWNVOTING AND CLOSING ?

Answer (score 2):

In `Person` you want to maintain the `Card` information using `card_no` property and also in `Card` entity you want to have `person_id` property. So what you are looking for is bidirectional relationship. Assuming that you are looking for `One-To-Many` bidirectional relationship then the mapping between the `Person` and `Card` entities will be as follows.

A `Person` can have many `Cards` so you need a set in Person class. The mapping is OneToMany so use `@OneToMany` and the `mappedBy` attribute tells what property in `Card` class represents the `Person` entity. I have used the property name `person` in the `Card` class so the `mappedBy` contains value as `person`.

```
@Entity(name="PERSON")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    private Set<Card> cards;
}
```

Now in `Card` class the relationship is `ManyToOne` towards the `Person` class so use the annotation `@ManyToOne`, here you can specify what is the name of the foreign key in `Card` table that points to the primary key of `Person` table. Here we can give any name to the foreign key, If you want to give it as `"parent_id` then add the annotation `@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")`

```
@Entity(name="CARD")
public class Card {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Person person;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#d5e3678

Change the line:

```
private int person_id;
```

For:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
private Person person;
```

Comment: Did you ever read anything about ORM (Object/relational mapping)?